# Receiving no events in contract receipt web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, receipts

In my contract interaction with web3js I have a

```
.once("receipt", async (receipt) => {
                    console.log("receipt:", receipt);
```

I run this with a firebase function. The receipt shows stuff like the transactionhash, to, status, logbloom, blockhash etc. etc. However there is no `events`object in there where i can check the return values my event is supposed to give:

```
event BetCompleted(uint256 indexed betId, address indexed winner, uint256 amount);
```

I've also read that the logs[0].topics is related to the events which looks to contain 3 adresses in my receipt.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong / how to read the event through the receipt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `receipt.logs` array. If it's empty it means no event was emitted.

If `BetCompleted` was emitted than `receipt.logs` should have a element `log` with the following fields:

- `address`: the address of the contract that emitted it.
- `topics[0]` = `web3.utils.sha3("BetCompleted(uint256,address,uint256)")` = `0x8a204c2634e61fa974cd81173313c7f47ce714e2bfe11f395233a751f52b0445`. This identifies the event.
- `topics[1]`: `betId` as a uint256.
- `topics[2]`: `winner` as an address padded with 0.
- `data`: `amount` as a uint256.

Comment: Late response but sweet, this helped me figure out to decode the event :)